# parsing unknown attributes of elements within an xml file using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, parsing, xml-attribute

Is it possible to get both the attribute name and the value of an element?

Basically i want to get the name and the values of all attributes of a single element, in order to write them into a Javascript Object like this:

```
obj {
  key: "value",
  another_key: "another_value",
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery you can get name and values of all attributes for specific element like that:

```
var obj = {}; // this object will hold key-value pairs of elem attributes
var attribs = $('#elem')[0].attributes;
for (var i = 0; i < attribs.length; i++) {
    obj[attribs[i].name] = attribs[i].value;
}
```

Remember to replace `'#elem'` with a valid selector for the element you want to get attributes from.